# Error while compiling with Laravel Mix - Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I've been using Laravel 8 beside Vue Js and they worked well together. I tried to start a project with Laravel and Vue Js again, but after a week it gave me an error. I used the commands below:
`Laravel v8.26.1 (PHP v7.4.3)`

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <project_name>
```

It works fine, after that:

```
npm install
```

Works well, too

But here's the error when I try running `npm run dev`

```html
npm run dev
> @ dev <project_path>
> npm run development


> @ development <project_path>
> mix

Error: You are using an unspported version of Node. Please update to at least Node v12.14
    at assertSupportedNodeVersion (<project_path>/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Engine.js:6:15)
    at executeScript (<project_path>/node_modules/laravel-mix/bin/cli.js:58:5)
    at Command.program.command.description.option.action.cmd (<project_path>/node_modules/laravel-mix/bin/cli.js:44:13)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (<project_path>/node_modules/commander/index.js:426:31)
    at Command._parseCommand (<project_path>/node_modules/commander/index.js:1002:14)
    at Command._dispatchSubcommand (<project_path>/node_modules/commander/index.js:953:18)
    at Command._parseCommand (<project_path>/node_modules/commander/index.js:979:12)
    at Command.parse <project_path>/node_modules/commander/index.js:801:10)
    at Command.parseAsync (<project_path>/node_modules/commander/index.js:828:10)
    at run (<project_path>/node_modules/laravel-mix/bin/cli.js:47:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-02-06T07_19_07_707Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-02-06T07_19_07_767Z-debug.log
```

package.json

```html
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
"dependencies": []
}
```

I didn't do something special or configure anything!
Thanks in advance ;D

Comment: You can see [in the laravel-mix package.json](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/package.json) it requires under `engines` `"node": ">=12.14.0"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to upgrade your node so try these commands:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

check node version by:

```
sudo node -v
```

it must show something like v14.*

You may need to restart your terminal to see the updated node version.

And then do `npm run dev`

Comment: Hey, It worked. Thanks for you help ;D . I've been searching a lot to solve this error but nothing found. Plus installation process is much faster than previous version. Amazing [persian = Chakeretim dadash]

Comment: This works!.Thank you,Make it as correct one..i spent lot of time on this.

Comment: @Dasunwijesundara I'm glad your problem was solved.